# Tasks or Actions for Plugins?

Tags: mvvmcross

I've noticed that many of the current plugins that have return values or multiple results use actions. For example, PictureChooserTask.TakePicture takes in an `Action<Stream>` for success and an Action for canceled.

What I want to know is why not have PictureChooserTask.TakePicture return a `Task<Stream>`? Are Tasks not supported cross platform?

Sorry if this is a noob question but I'm coming from Windows and haven't taken any of my mvvmcross projects to other platforms yet. I prefer to use Tasks but I want to make sure I'm following the right pattern before I write my first plugin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to know is why not have PictureChooserTask.TakePicture return a Task? Are Tasks not supported cross platform?

The original MvvmCross plugins were made before `async` was available on any platform, and at a time before the `BCL.Async` portable packages were licensed for use beyond Microsoft Windows platforms. Because of these two factors, neither `Task` nor `async` was not used.

However, `async` is now available on all platforms and there have been some excellent recent changes to licensing from Microsoft.

Because of this, plugins are now free to use both `Task` and `async`

For an example of a plugin using `Task` take a look at some of the plugins in https://github.com/Cheesebaron/Cheesebaron.MvxPlugins - e.g. at https://github.com/Cheesebaron/Cheesebaron.MvxPlugins/tree/master/Connectivity/

Note that when building a plugin that uses `Task`, the "core" portable library will probably need to be based on either PCL profile 158 or profile 78. If choosing 158, then the plugin will need to reference the `BCL.Async` portable nuget package in order to use `Task`. If choosing 78, then `Task` will be available without additional packages - the only loss will be that your plugin will then not be available back to Silverlight or to any projects which themselves choose to use profile 158.